# Google Places API for iOS not letting me cancel or select

Tags: ios, swift, google-places-api

I have followed the Places API tutorial on Google's website, and I have double checked that the Places API for iOS is enabled and that my API key is in my AppDelegate. I have definitely implemented GMSPlacePickerViewControllerDelegate in my class. The Places Picker will open, I can view places, and I can tap on them, and I can search. I cannot get out of this screen, I cannot cancel, I cannot actually select anything or return a location. This is the same on a physical device and on the simulator. Why doesn't it work, and how can I make it work?

```
@IBAction func selectLocationPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    let config = GMSPlacePickerConfig(viewport: nil)
    let placePicker = GMSPlacePickerViewController(config: config)
    present(placePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

// To receive the results from the place picker 'self' will need to conform to
// GMSPlacePickerViewControllerDelegate and implement this code.
func placePicker(_ viewController: GMSPlacePickerViewController, 
didPick place: GMSPlace) {
// Dismiss the place picker, as it cannot dismiss itself.
viewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

print("Place name \(place.name)")
print("Place address \(place.formattedAddress)")
print("Place attributions \(place.attributions)")
}

func placePickerDidCancel(_ viewController: 
GMSPlacePickerViewController) {
// Dismiss the place picker, as it cannot dismiss itself.
viewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

print("No place selected")
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implement GMSPlacePickerViewControllerDelegate protocol in your class and set `placePicker.delegate = self`

Comment: I was about to add this myself, after going through some projects on GitHub and working out what I'd missed! Thanks